# python: annotation for ellipsis to be a possible argument of a function

Tags: python, annotations, ellipsis

For "certain reasons" I want to allow python's Ellipsis "..." to (also) be an argument to some function (let's say) f, e.g. as follows:

```
def f(arg: ?) -> None:
    print(arg)

f(...)
```

what annotation should I use for arg?

Comment: Please elaborate that 'certain reason'

Comment: there is a lot of context unnecessary to post here. If I code f(5) then "arg: int" or if I code f('barfoo') then "arg: str", i.e. there is a corresponding type annotation for whatever is supposed to go into f. However what type annotation should I use when the argument is neither integer, nor string, but the Ellipsis?

Comment: pycharm appears to accept "type(Ellipsis)", i.e. "def f(arg: type(Ellipsis)):". However I doubt this the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears (see python doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) that

```
from types import EllipsisType

def f(arg: EllipsisType):
    print(arg)

f(...)  # or alternatively f(Ellipsis)
```

is the right solution here (i.e. to annotate the Ellipsis itself)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: edited according to bot's advice

Answer (score 0):

`...` is an instance of the `Ellipsis` class, so you could do something like:

```
def f(arg:Ellipsis) -> None:
    # your code
```

*Since there is only one instance of that class, you probably want to combine it with some other types.  Otherwise why have a parameter at all (could it be a way to detect all calls to function `f` by temporarily setting an unusable type)*

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did not check this with mypy yet, but pycharm infers from "arg:Ellipsis" that arg could be "Any". Instead when I write "arg: type(Ellipsis)" then pycharm infers right. I am not sure wether this is a pycharm specific bug/feature.